# Advanced query in Rails with multiple joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have a table of people. I also have a table of events; each event has multiple shows (, each show has multiple tickets, and each ticket may or may not have a buyer (a person). Each person can have multiple tickets to different events though.

My current attempt looks like this:

```
Person.joins(tickets: {shows: :events}).where("events.id" => 1)
```

And it generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT *
  FROM "people"
  INNER JOIN "tickets"
    ON "tickets"."buyer_id" = "people"."id"
  INNER JOIN "shows"
    ON "shows"."id" = "tickets"."show_id"
  INNER JOIN "events"
    ON "events"."id" = "shows"."event_id"
WHERE
  "events"."id" = 1;
```

But my understanding is that the query will only return one ticket for each person. I don't know my joins that well, but would it be safe to assume that I need a right outer join between people and tickets, in order to have every ticket shown (and therefore every event represented). Is this correct? And how do I implement THAT in ActiveRecord/Arel?

**How do I find all of the people that have tickets to a specific event?**

Comment: This query will actually return people and not tickets. Can you please clarify your goal?

Comment: I want to find all of the people that have tickets to a specific event.

Comment: So I think your query should do the trick. Are you expecting something different when a person has more than one ticket?

Comment: If a person has more than one ticket, then don't they only have one ticket returned per row? This doesn't guarantee that the ticket that's returned is the same ticket that matches the event I'm looking for. Therefore, if one person buys tickets to multiple events, I'm liable to miss them if the query returns the wrong ticket. Which is why I thought maybe I needed a right outer join. No idea on how to implement it though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm also not a DB expert, but according to what I know this is the way it will work:

1. **people inner join tickets** will give you a row for every ticket owned
   by a person (which will contain duplicate people entries if a person has more than one ticket)
2. **inner join show** will just add the show to the row
   (assuming every ticket belongs to one show only)
3. **inner join event** will just add the event information (assuming every show belongs to one event only)
4. **where event.id=1** will leave in the table only the rows with event id 1

I think this is what you're looking for.

BTW, the naming convention in the code above suggests you might have a problem with the definition of the relation. I would expect it to be:

`Person.joins(tickets: {show: :event})` and not

`Person.joins(tickets: {shows: :events})` since ticket belongs_to a single show and show belongs_to a single event. Am I missing something?

Comment: That was it. I didn't expect people to be multiplied by the amount of tickets that there were, but that is the result I was looking for. The query is working, thanks!